# How to manage users in linux without using adduser/useradd

Tags: linux, perl

I have to create a perl script that allows me to add/delete/modify users from my Debian. I've read that is not recommended but I've been asked to do it without using system calls, so no adduser/useradd allowed.  This script should check if a user has been added/deleted from a mysql database and then add the user to the system. Maybe by modifying etc/passwd directly? Is there any perl module to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got [Unix::Passw::File](http://search.cpan.org/~sharyanto/Unix-Passwd-File-0.12/lib/Unix/Passwd/File.pm) after quick CPAN search. This module can be used read and manipulate password file entries.

Comment: This is just what I needed, I have tested it and it works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

On most distributions nowadays, there is also a file /etc/shadow that is used in conjunction with /etc/passwd, so you most likely would have to add a line to /etc/shadow as well.  In addition, you most likely would have to create a home directory and a group for the new user, as well as a few other steps.  See http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/adduser.html the steps involved in creating a new user manually.

Having said all of the above, I'm curious to know what the objection is to simply using `useradd` called from the perl script.  If it is done safely (i.e. inputs are sanitized to prevent a command line injection attack), this approach seems to be a lot simpler and less error prone than trying to script perl to add a user by doing all of the above steps.

Comment: Hello mti2935 and thank you for your answer! I also don't know why my teacher wants me to do it this way, might be security reasons but if you say is not a problem then i do not know either.